# Eigenvalue and eigenvector in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, mathematics

I want to calculate eigenvectors and eigenvalues for real symmetric matrix or Hermitian matrix. Can I use this: https://qiskit.org/documentation/api/qiskit.aqua.components.eigs.Eigenvalues.html

Answer (score 2):

If that is all you want to do then SciPy is really the way to go. Indeed, qiskit just wraps that functionality when requesting a classical answer. 
In SciPy you can use [scipy.linalg.eig](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html). You can find examples of using this function in the documentation.

Comment: where can i find an example how can i use it?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html#scipy.linalg.eigh